# Getting Bot Variable Into Different Commando Files

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I use commando for my discord.js bot, and it's linked to the client. I want to be able to use the bot variable in a different file, mainly to help check if the bot has the correct permissions.

My Bot variable:

```
const bot = new commando.Client({
    commandPrefix: '!',
    owner: config.ownerID,
    unknownCommandResponse: false
});
```

This is currently in my index.js file, but is there a way for me to be able to use it in a different command file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

**index.js**

```
const bot = new commando.Client({
commandPrefix: '!',
owner: config.ownerID,
unknownCommandResponse: false
});

this.bot = bot
```

This would then be accessed in another file like:

```
this.bot.(property)
```

All the properties of `bot` will be accessible as long as you use the above mentioned method.